# Как отправить запрос правильно?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Добрый вечер!

Имеются два `select` в первом 3 даты:

- 20.02.18,
- 21.02.18,
- 22.02.18.

Во втором мне нужно, чтобы загружались данные из базы, где таблица равна выбранной дате. Загрузить надо из столбика `group`

```
SELECT `group` FROM `21.02.18` ORDER BY `group`
```

Без обновления страницы, знаю что нужно связать тут ajax + jquery + php, помогите пожалуйста :)

---

### Дополню и переформулирую:

Мне нужно, чтобы выбранное значение из первого select'а отправлялось методом POST в php скрипт, а оттуда нужно чтобы пришёл ответ. После того, как придёт этот ответ, нужно чтобы в select №2 появились пункты, из БД где название таблицы - это выбранный нами пункт в первом select.

Comment: Подробнее опиши проблему и добавь описания таблиц, я не понимаю что ты хочешь сделать.

Comment: Имееются два select'а
один имеет в себе 3 даты.
И имеется второй select, но в нём пункты должны загружаться из БД, 
пример запроса в бд такое (для второго селекта): ( SELECT group FROM 21.02.18 ORDER BY group ) - там где 21.02.18 - это то, что мы выбрали.
Без перезагрузки страницы, с помощью ajax+jquery+php
Надеюсь понятно объяснил

Comment: @Kronka Обновите вопрос, добавьте информацию из комментария

Comment: Ответ тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/789436/Как-реализовать-это-через-ajaxphp